# Позиционирование по центру при помощи флексов

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как это меню позиционировать по центру? И как добавить эти белые точки между ними или как их сделать белыми?

```css
/*second-footer*/

.second-footer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}


.footer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 76%;
    border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px 180px 0 25px;
}


/*end second-footer*/
```

```html
 <div class="second-footer">
        <div class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как-то так можна. стыли можете сами далее оформить

```css
/*second-footer*/

.second-footer .footer ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.footer ul li {
margin-left:14px;
list-style:none;
position:relative;
}
.footer ul li a {text-decoration: none;
  color: white;}
.footer ul li:before{
 content: "";
width: 4px;
height: 4px;
background: white;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: -9px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -2px;
 }
 .footer ul li:first-child:before{content:none;}
.footer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 76%;
    border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px 180px 0 25px;
    background:blue;
}


/*end second-footer*/
```

```html
 <div class="second-footer">
        <div class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

display - flex должен быть родитель. забыл...  а что касается цвета этих самых точек  коммент в css...

```css
/*second-footer*/

.second-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap height:100px;
}

li {
  background: red;
  color: green;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: inherit;
  /*наследует значение родителя*/
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 76%;
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px 180px 0 25px;
}


/*end second-footer*/
```

```html
<div class="second-footer">
  <div class="footer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Our Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```